# PHP Array Code is not working in PHP 7.2.26

Tags: php, arrays

I have one code of PHP Array which is stop working as I have changed my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2.26. My code was working in old PHP version 5.6 but not working in new version 7.2.26.

Code as below

```
while($row_country = $res_country->fetch())
{
    $country[]=array( "country" => $row_country['country_name']);
}
```

I am storing countries name in country array.

Output of PHP 5.6 as below

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [country] => Thailand ) 
    [1] => Array ( [country] => Spain ) 
    [2] => Array ( [country] => Indonesia ) 
    [3] => Array ( [country] => France ) 
    [4] => Array ( [country] => France ) 
    [5] => Array ( [country] => Peru ) 
)
```

But in PHP 7.2.26 is not showing anything.

I have checked that I am able to `echo $row_country['country_name'];` country name in `while loop` but issue with `array code`.

My Connection string as below

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=ip;", 'user', 'pwd') or die(print_r($conn->error));
```

Please guide to resolve issue.

Comment: which database driver you are using to get data from database?

Comment: @Hassaan No issue with database. I am able to fetching country name in while loop. But issue with array.

Comment: Thats a really unnecessarity complex array even if it does work

Comment: There is no obvious reason why that while loop would not do exectly the same thing in PHP5.6 and 7.2 I would check that you are actually getting the expected result from the query

Comment: `PHP 7.2.26 is not showing anything` - U did check the error logs right?

Comment: @DarkBee No errors shows on page. :(

Comment: can you show us a `var_dump($country);` please. run after the while loop

Comment: Try some logging/echoing to see what it's doing. Such as `echo "About to head into the loop";` before the loop, `echo "Inside the loop";` inside, and `echo "Complete";` after. That way you can see the progress of the script and what it's doing.

Comment: @aynber I have done this. after loop not working. Inside loop below array code line working. after array code line not working.

Comment: @RiggsFolly after loop not working